# Best Way to Replace UserControl Loaded in TabControl TabItem

Tags: wpf, xaml, user-controls, tabcontrol, tabitem

I currently have a TabControl loaded in MainWindow.xaml, which has three tabs. Let's name them Tab1, Tab2 and Tab3.

The individual tabs have views (usercontrols) supplied and they all work as expected. Code as follows. I am using MahApps Metro TabControl here.

```
<Controls:MetroAnimatedSingleRowTabControl Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" x:Name="MainTabControl">
            <TabItem Header="Tab1">
                <view:Tab1View DataContext="{Binding}"  />
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="Tab2">
                <view:Tab2View DataContext="{Binding}" />
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="Tab3">                    
                <view:Tab3View DataContext="{Binding}" />
            </TabItem>                
        </Controls:MetroAnimatedSingleRowTabControl>
```

What I would like to do now is to switch the view of Tab3 (which is Tab3View.xaml) to another view (let's call it subTab3View.xaml) when I click on a button on Tab3View.xaml. This will basically switch the Tab3 content from Tab3View.xaml to subTab3View.xaml.

Could anyone kindly suggest me a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a content control in your tab, and then change the content on button click or whatever event you want.

```
<TabItem Header="Tab3">                    
    <ContentControl x:Name="contentControl"/>
</TabItem>                


private void ButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.contentControl.Content = new Tab3View();
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I was trying to think of ways to achieve it though xaml triggers but your method seems to be the shortest and easily readable. Thanks again

Comment: You can change content with triggers as well but If you are happy coding in code behind, this is the best way to go fwd. Happy coding :)

Comment: Would it be possible to achieve the same results by means of just triggers in xaml? That particular tab page is meant for a quick launcher to other sub tools I am working on so I wasn't planning to create a viewmodel for it in the beginning.